# mysqldump command works differently between linux and macos

Tags: macos, amazon-rds, mysql-5.7, rhel7

I'm trying to do a mysqldump from my Mac. I'm accessing an AWS RDB using MySQL 5.7. The SQL is as follows:

`/usr/local/bin/mysqldump -u confluenceuser -pPASSWD -h mydatabase.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306 --verbose --max_allowed_packet=2147483648 --routines --triggers confluence_qa_710 > confluence_qa_710-20210520.sql`

I'm getting the following error:

```
-- Connecting to mydatabase.rds.amazonaws.com...
-- Retrieving table structure for table AO_05769A_VISIT_ENTITY...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME,                       JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM, '$."number-of-buckets-specified"')                FROM information_schema.COLUMN_STATISTICS                WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'confluence_qa_710' AND TABLE_NAME = 'AO_05769A_VISIT_ENTITY';': Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS' in information_schema (1109)
```

The same SQL statement works fine on my linux machine (changing to /usr/bin/mysqldump). There is some difference in the SQL versions on the two machines. I installed using Homebrew on the Mac

```
% mysqldump --version
mysqldump  Ver 8.0.25 for macos10.15 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
```

it was already installed on the Linux (RHEL7) system (through yum?)

```
$ mysqldump --version
mysqldump  Ver 10.14 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)
```

How can I get the mysqldump to work on my Mac?